# Using Bernoulli's Theorem to find the maximum flow speed on a Streamline

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Suppose you are given a compressible fluid, with a known flow speed and Mach number, at a point A. The maximum flow speed on the streamline that passes through A can be calculated by using Bernoulli's Theorem (BT) because the fluid is compressible, which is a condition of BT. Where BT is:

[image]

Seeing as the maximum flow speed is what we want, BT can be set equal to itself for the parameters of maximum flow speed, giving:

[image]

Where B is accounting for the parameters for maximum flow, however, an assumption can be made using BT. Such is, for maximum Flow speed, Pressure is zero:

[image]

And because no pressures are involved in the initial statement, it is best to eliminate these terms with something that can be solved:

[image]

Finally giving a general soltuion to this problem of

[image]

of which [image] can be found ( for example, with air)

---

I am unsure on the assumptions i have made.

When the BT is set equal for A and B, is this plausible? as well as the Assumption for maximum Flow speed at zero pressure?